# Block incoming traffic on WAN with iptables on simple router kills outgoing traffic (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I struggling with just dropping incoming traffic on a simple Ubuntu machine that acts as NAT router.

What I did so far:

I activated `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

To have NAT i activated following in iptables

```
sudo iptables ! -o lo -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Fine everything works as expected.

Now I want to drop incoming traffic on the WAN interface.
Therefore I did following:

```
# SSH still allowed
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT )
```

And then:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
```

Unfortunately the last command blocks, all http traffic on the machine itself.
No outgoing traffic is allowed anymore.
From the NAT machines it still works.

So the rule `sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP`
seems to be the wrong if I just want to block traffic from the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that a (tcp) connection transfers data in both directions: a command as simple as `curl google.com` involves:

- Query a DNS server
- Receive a reply from a DNS server
- Send an HTTP request to a remote website
- Receive the HTTP response from a remote website

If you block all incoming traffic with `-A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP`, you will be blocking the "Receive..." portion of all of those transactions. You need to minimally permit traffic that is associated with an `ESTABLISHED` connection. For what you're doing, a simple firewall might look like:

```
# Allow RELATED and ESTABLISHED traffic
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow ICMP traffic
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# Allow all traffic on lo. This isn't strictly necessary for what you're
# doing, but it helps avoid shooting yourself in the foot later
# on.
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow new ssh connections
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Reject anything else coming in on eth0. You could use
# DROP here if you prefer.
-A INPUT -i eth0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

(This is the based on the default set of firewall rules created by the `iptables-services` package on Fedora.)

Comment: Great, thank you so much!!! 
I just couldn't find it explained that well anywhere.

In particular, I should avoid using the host as a router from the Internet. But that should be given with the last rule. Perfect thank you

Could anyone note this as answer? I haven't got enough reputation so far, as I reconnected my account. Thank you.

Comment: Only you can accept this answer, because you’re the one who asked the question. There’s no reputation requirement for being able to accept an answer.

Comment: Ah thank you. I got it :-)